# uncaught rangeerror maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: ajax, symfony, uncaught-exception

```
           $(document).ready(function(){
               $( "#add1" ).click(function(){

                   var nom1 = $('#nom1').val();
                   var cont1 = $('#con1').val();
                   var part1 = $('#par1').val();
                   var coup1 = $('#coup1').val();


                       $.ajax({
                           type:'POST',
                           data:{nom1:nom1,con1:con1,par1:part1,coup1:coup1},
                           url:'{{path('equipe_add')}}'



                       });


               });
               return false;
           });

   </script>
```

Can you help me ,I got uncaught rangeerror maximum call stack size exceeded on each time i click.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. This page https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is a really great resource you may want to read over before submitting a question. If you follow these guidelines people in the community will be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to write correctly where is your `ajax`:

this:

```
url:'{{path('equipe_add')}}'
```

to

```
url:"{{path('equipe_add')}}"
```

Syntax error in twig

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try this :

```
var url = '{{path('equipe_add')}}';
```

and than in the ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data:{nom1:nom1,con1:con1,par1:part1,coup1:coup1},
        url : url
 });
```